# Using kramdown in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add some Markdown styling to my Rails 3 blog application. This should be something simple, but I can't get it to work.

I have `kramdown` in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'kramdown'
```

I ran `bundle install`. I have an application helper called `kramdown`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def kramdown(text)
    require 'kramdown'
    return Kramdown::Document.new(text).to_html
  end
end
```

And in my view script:

```
<%= kramdown(@post.body) %>
```

I'm getting the error message:

> no such file to load -- kramdown

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

I've just started experimenting with Kramdown.

Got it working simply by adding to gem file, bundle install, then putting the following in my view.

```
<%= Kramdown::Document.new(@project.body).to_html %>
```

Reckon your problem is the *require 'kramdown'* line. With Rails this is probably getting added behind the scenes. I suspect the kramdown documentation is more focused on Ruby than Rails specifically. The dev server did need restarting too.

Using your suggestion of making a helper, the following works for me.

Application helper:

```
def kramdown(text)
  return Kramdown::Document.new(text).to_html
end
```

View:

```
<%= kramdown @project.body %>
```

I did run into a problem though. All of kramdown's HTML code was visible as Rails was making the HTML safe. To solve this I added sanitize to the helper function:

```
def kramdown(text)
  return sanitize Kramdown::Document.new(text).to_html
end
```

Comment: I think I might have forgotten to restart the dev server.